# Exception Bubbling in .net

Tags: c#, exception

What is exception bubbling and in real time where we use this concept and also what is the need to use bubbling up the exceptions ?
I am very much confused with bubbling the exceptions why because i have gone through many sites no has given clear idea about that , and also i have a doubt with what is the diff. b/w Catch;    Catch e;

Comment: Still i have a doubt where we will use this concept ,is it good or bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't catch an exception in your code, it will propagate to the caller. Often this is absolutely fine: it is not true that you should catch all exceptions - in fact, the most common response to an exception is "let it keep escalating". For that reason, `finally` is more common that `catch` in a lot of code (for resource xleanup) - although `using` is even more common than `finally`.

As for `catch` vs `catch(Exception e)` - the second form catches a specific set of exception types (in this case, `Exception` and any subclass), and provides access to the exception for inspection. This could be because you want to check specific properties of the exception (a SQL error code, for example), or because you want to raise a custom exception using the original exception as the `InnerException`. For example:

```
catch(AwesomeException e) {
    if(e.Something)
        throw new CrazyException(" oops", e);
    throw; // else rethrow the original
}
```

Note that in .NET 1.1, it was also possible that some exceptions *weren't* `Exception`s - in C++ you can throw *anything* - however, .NET 2 and above fix this (unless you specifically disable it) by wrapping non-`Exception` exceptions in a wrapper.

Comment: if you have a code, share it with me and also give a real time example so that i can use it

Comment: please explain still i am unclear about Bubbling of exceptions

Comment: @Vinod Foo() calls Bar() which calls Blap(). Blap throws an exception. Bar doesn't attempt to catch the exception (or catches it and rethrows it) - so Foo gets the exception. And up and up until either somebody handles the exception, or it reaches the top of a thread, and kills the process.